# taking input form wix installer UI and storing in a text file

Tags: wix

I have a text file which contains user specific parameters.
The parameters are later used by the application to perform certain tasks.

Currently the user has to update the fields after the installation.

Is it possible to do this via installer UI, ie take input and update the .txt file.

**EDIT**

The text file is like

A=

B=

C=

And I have to update the fields after =

Comment: It could be done with a custom action. The scenario sounds a little peculiar, though, so I'm wondering if there isn't a better approach to the overall problem.

Comment: How does the file containing parameter(s) look like? Can it be overwritten or does it have to update just a certain value?

Comment: It can be done by custom action. if you can use a ini file instead of text file, it would be easier to read. besides WIX have <IniFile> element for that. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/inifile.html